# Modifying exception message without losing stack from raise

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I've got a `try/except` clause that will either return or catch a `KeyError` as follows:

```
try:
    return super().__new__(globals()[kls])
except KeyError:
    raise
```

This will generate a stack trace when used improperly like so:

```
>>> g = Grid(cell='Circle')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    g = Grid(cell='Circle')
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 8, in __new__
    return super().__new__(globals()[kls])
KeyError: 'SHPCircleGrid'
>>> g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    g
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

And that is perfectly fine, however I want to "extend/modify" the message to explain to the user how to avoid this error again; i.e. go from:

`KeyError: 'SHPCircleGrid'`

to

`KeyError: 'SHPCircleGrid'. Use 'Hex', 'Rect' or 'Tri' for cell keyword.`

While maintaining the stack for the user. A generic `print()` in the catching portion sets `g` to `NoneType` which I would not like, so simply printing is not the way to handle this. Adding another `raise KeyError('some message')` prints two stacks (the "while handling exception another..." message) which is also undesired.

What is the appropriate way to handle this such that it could be extended to any additional keywords that the class instantiation may throw a `KeyError` for?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just achieve that by supplying your message to `KeyError` as such:

```
try:
    return super().__new__(globals()[kls])
except KeyError as e:
    key = "'{}'".format(*e.args)
    base = "{}. Use 'Hex', 'Rect' or 'Tri' for cell keyword."
    raise KeyError(base.format(key)) from None
```

Comment: `raise KeyError(...) from e` is probably a better idea than mutating the original exception

Comment: @AnthonySottile like that? wasn't even aware of the ability to do that

Comment: Im trying to avoid raising multiple errors; this generates two separate stacks. I just wanted to extend the message of the original error.

Comment: try now @pstatix

Comment: It does avoid the two stacks, but I feel like its a lot. I could simple do a check at the beginning of the method to see if cell is a valid keyword and raise a custom KeyError without doing all that. I don't understand why I cannot just extend the message.

Comment: No I mean it feels like a lot going around what could be a very simple extension. Where one could use the stack from the exception already raised and expand the content such as `e.message += 'some message'`.

Comment: technically you can do that but you would be modifying the original exception as @AnthonySottile mentioned and i don’t know if that is considered best practice